# Python does not create file on mounted drive

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, aix

I wrote a python code like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
f=open("/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements/statement/guru99.txt","w+")
```

i tried to create file on mounted drive (on AIX)

```
  node       mounted        
-------- ---------------  ---------------  ------ ------------ ---------------
clsfs038 /Bank_statements /inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements
```

...and i got error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements/statement/guru99.txt'
```

same code for local path is working ok!

I create file on mounted drive by bash without any problem.

It's df:

```
[inform@xxx/inform ] $ df
Filesystem    512-blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/hd10opt     1966080    380432   81%    15329    24% /opt
/dev/livedump      65536     64864    2%        4     1% /var/adm/ras/livedump
/dev/informlv 1257766912 662083576   48%   425081     1% /inform
clsfs038:/Bank_statements  2576863224 393165352   85%        0     0% /inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements
```

permission on folder:

```
[inform@xxx /inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements ] $ ls -la
total 184
drwxrwxr-x    1 inform   inform        16384 Dec 19 16:44 .
drwxr-xr-x   19 inform   inform        32768 Dec 18 17:16 ..
drwxrwxr-x    1 inform   inform        16384 Dec 19 14:08 load
drwxrwxr-x    1 inform   inform        16384 Dec 19 10:37 statement
-rwxrwxr-x    1 inform   inform            0 Nov 22 12:26 testfile
-rwxrwxr-x    1 inform   inform            0 Dec 18 13:06 testfile2
```

Mount:

```
[inform@xxx /inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements ] $ mount
  node       mounted        mounted over    vfs       date        options
-------- ---------------  ---------------  ------ ------------ ---------------
         /dev/hd4         /                jfs2   Aug 26 17:39 rw,log=/dev/hd8
         /dev/hd2         /usr             jfs2   Aug 26 17:39 rw,log=/dev/hd8
         /dev/hd9var      /var             jfs2   Aug 26 17:39 rw,log=/dev/hd8
         /dev/hd3         /tmp             jfs2   Aug 26 17:40 rw,log=/dev/hd8
         /dev/hd1         /home            jfs2   Aug 26 17:40 rw,log=/dev/hd8
         /dev/hd11admin   /admin           jfs2   Aug 26 17:40 rw,log=/dev/hd8
         /proc            /proc            procfs Aug 26 17:40 rw
         /dev/hd10opt     /opt             jfs2   Aug 26 17:40 rw,log=/dev/hd8
         /dev/livedump    /var/adm/ras/livedump jfs2   Aug 26 17:40 rw,log=/dev/hd8
         /dev/informlv    /inform          jfs2   Aug 26 17:40 rw,log=INLINE
         /dev/zabbixapplv /opt/zabbixapp   jfs2   Aug 26 17:40 rw,log=INLINE
clsfs042 /sap_employee    /inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles/SAP cifs   Aug 26 17:40 rw,uid=482,gid=482,fmode=775,wrkgrp=RCCF,noprompt
clsfs042 /Applications    /inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/Popcorn/Informatica cifs   Aug 26 17:40 rw,uid=482,gid=482,fmode=775,wrkgrp=RCCF,noprompt
clsfs041 /AFS             /inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/afs cifs   Aug 26 17:40 rw,uid=482,gid=482,fmode=775,wrkgrp=RCCF,noprompt
clsfs038 /DetOtchet       /inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles/CB_PORTF cifs   Aug 26 17:40 rw,uid=482,gid=482,fmode=775,wrkgrp=RCCF,noprompt
clsfs038 /BALANS          /inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/BALANS cifs   Aug 26 17:40 rw,uid=482,gid=482,fmode=775,wrkgrp=RCCF,noprompt
clsfs040 /Workgroups      /inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/Metodologiya cifs   Aug 26 17:40 rw,uid=482,gid=482,fmode=775,wrkgrp=RCCF,noprompt
clsfs038 /Workgroups3     /inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/ALM_REPORT cifs   Aug 26 17:40 rw,uid=482,gid=482,fmode=775,wrkgrp=RCCF,noprompt
clsfs042 /Applications    /inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles/rccf_applications cifs   Nov 12 12:20 rw,uid=482,gid=482,fmode=775,wrkgrp=RCCF
clsfs038 /Bank_statements /inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements cifs   Nov 22 12:27 rw,uid=482,gid=482,fmode=775,wrkgrp=RCCF
```

Result of command (stackoverflow asked me some more details, without this text i cant edit my post with this code):

```
[inform@xxx /inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/Scripts/STATEMENT ] $ /inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/Scripts/STATEMENT/test/stack.py
 False
 READ False
 WRITE False
/inform True
/inform READ True
/inform WRITE True
/inform/app True
/inform/app READ True
/inform/app WRITE True
/inform/app/Informatica True
/inform/app/Informatica READ True
/inform/app/Informatica WRITE True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0 True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0 READ True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0 WRITE True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server READ True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server WRITE True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared READ True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared WRITE True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles READ True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles WRITE True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements READ True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements WRITE True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements/statement True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements/statement READ True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements/statement WRITE True
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements/statement/guru99.txt False
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements/statement/guru99.txt READ False
/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements/statement/guru99.txt WRITE False
```

Help me please)

Regards,
Alex

Comment: If you misspelled a directory along the way, it will fail

Comment: That errno seems to imply that the path doesn't exist. Can you verify that you can access the file using that path from the command line? If you can, it may be a permission issue as well. ALSO: It looks like the mounted drive is /Bank_statements, but I don't see that in your path?

Comment: Consider doing ls of the copy-and-pasted folder name on the command line

Comment: More related to the mount output: I'm not sure what I'm looking at for the mount output there. Is /Bank_statements your local mountpoint and the next column the remote folder? If so your path should be: `/Bank_statements/guru99.txt`

Comment: I checked path hundered times. It's ok.
/Bank_statements it is folder on Windows Share (samba). It is just a folder at node clsfs038.
Actually, i tried this path /Bank_statements/guru99.txt and many another like:
clsfs038:/Bank_statements and etc.

Comment: Ok, but I'd still encourage you to try and `ls` that path from the machine you're running the python on. I'm convinced that the `/inform/app/ ... ` path exists on the shared drive and the mountpoint is `/Bank_statements`. Change your path to `/Bank_statements/guru99.txt`.

Comment: It's df:
[inform@xxx/inform ] $ df
Filesystem    512-blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/hd10opt     1966080    380432   81%    15329    24% /opt
/dev/livedump      65536     64864    2%        4     1% /var/adm/ras/livedump
/dev/informlv 1257766912 662083576   48%   425081     1% /inform
clsfs038:/Bank_statements  2576863224 393165352   85%        0     0% /inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements

Comment: Ok, so I had it backwards. Disregard the suggestion above then. It is likely permissions if you can `ls` that path then. Verify that the user you're running the python as has write permissions to that directory.

Comment: I created dir/file at this path by bash with same user.

Comment: As you can see, posting a directory listing in comments doesn't really work. Please [edit] your question to included a properly formatted snippet to demonstrate that `statement` is an existing directory which you have write access to in the directory shown in the mount.

Comment: Done. I updated the main thread.

Comment: One more ask: Can you show the output of `mount` please?

Comment: `strace(1)` could help: run `strace -f /usr/bin/python yourscipt.py 2>debug.log` then examine file `debug.log`

Comment: Added it at main post.

Comment: Running out of ideas tbh. Can you post the output of `id` ran as the user who is running the python?

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste result of following script ? Just in case it helps find out anything

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

file_name = "/inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements/statement/guru99.txt"

dirs = file_name.split("/")

for i in range(len(dirs)):
    dir_to_check = "/".join(dirs[:i+1])
    print(dir_to_check + " " + str(os.path.exists(dir_to_check)))
    print(dir_to_check + " READ " + str(os.access(dir_to_check, os.R_OK)))
    print(dir_to_check + " WRITE " + str(os.access(dir_to_check, os.W_OK)))
```

Comment: Paste it on the main post.

Comment: That output doesn't show any problem with hierarchy or permissions. How about if you use relative path (i.e. just file name) instead of full path and run the script from directory /inform/app/Informatica/10.1.0/server/infa_shared/TgtFiles/bank_statements/statement/